# Firebird 2.5 Superclassic error on detach

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

Im running the latest `firebird 2.5-26780` SuperClassic on OSX10.10 running on localhost. Using the C api, and following examples shown [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/XE7/en/Disconnecting_from_Databases) -- essentially just running:

```
isc_detach_database(status_vector, &databaseHandle);
```

at the end of my program, I noticed

`INET/inet_error: read errno = 9` showing up in my `firebird.log` each instance that I disconnect from my database. I see no ill-effects from this, but logging errors can't be good news. Am I doing something wrong, or missing something obvious?

Comment: The error would seem to indicate the client attempts to use the socket after it has been closed already.

Comment: Agreed. Though, I can't figure out who is trying to use the socket, and why.  The C code very clearly runs the `isc_detach_database()` function then exits the program. The only thing I can assume is that its one of the pthreads created by firebird itself.

Comment: Did you commit your transaction before detaching, and have you checked that the status vector doesn't contain an error?